# Sorting an array of object based on key existence and value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects. For eg-

```
[{
    aKey:2, 
    bKey:2, 
    cKey:3
}, { 
    bKey:2, 
    cKey:6
}, {
    aKey:1,
    bKey:6, 
    cKey:5
}, {
    bKey:1, 
    cKey:4
}, {
    bKey:6, 
    cKey:7
}]
```

So what I need to do is-

1. First sort the array on the basis of aKey (asc order) and the objects which are having this key would be at the beginning in result array.
2. Then I need to sort the array based on the value of bKey. for eg, all the records having bKey = 2, would be at the beginning.
3. Rest records would be sorted based on the value of cKey in asc order.

So the output will be-

```
[{
    aKey:1,
    bKey:6, 
    cKey:5
}, {
    aKey:2, 
    bKey:2, 
    cKey:3
}, { 
    bKey:2, 
    cKey:6
}, {
    bKey:1, 
    cKey:4
}, {
    bKey:6, 
    cKey:7
}]
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @JLRishe: how to sort the array of object like I explained? first object is input and second one should be the output.

Comment: Why is `bKey:1` following `bKey:2` at expected output? Sort is based on `cKey`?

Comment: @guest271314: because I need to arrange the array in that way, objects having bKey = 2, would be the first.

Comment: What issue are you having sorting the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sorting preferentially from `aKey` to `bKey` and then to `cKey`, you can use this:

```js
var array=[{aKey:2,bKey:2,cKey:3},{bKey:2,cKey:6},{aKey:1,bKey:6,cKey:5},{bKey:1,cKey:4},{bKey:6,cKey:7}]

var result = array.sort(function(hash) {
  return function(a, b) {
    return ((a.aKey || Infinity) - (b.aKey || Infinity)) 
    || ((a.bKey || Infinity) - (b.bKey || Infinity)) 
    || ((a.cKey || Infinity) - (b.cKey || Infinity))
  }
}(Object.create(null)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

> But you want `bKey:2` to come before `bKey:1` as for the last element
>   that has `aKey`, the value of `bKey` is `2`.

To adjust for this *anomaly*, without knowing which element is to follow once `aKey` is done with (and extending to the case where `bKey` is also done with too), you can do this - hash these *anomaly keys* and sort accordingly - see demo below:

```js
var array=[{aKey:2,bKey:2,cKey:3},{aKey:1,bKey:6,cKey:5},{bKey:1,cKey:4},{bKey:6,cKey:7},{bKey:2,cKey:7},{bKey:2,cKey:6},{cKey:4},{cKey:7}]

var result = array.sort(function(hash) {
  return function(a, b) {
    // find the anomaly keys
    a.aKey && !b.aKey && (hash.bkey = a.bKey);
    a.bKey && !b.bKey && (hash.ckey = a.cKey);
    // sort criteria
    return ((a.aKey || Infinity) - (b.aKey || Infinity)) 
    || (((a.bKey != hash.bkey) - (b.bKey != hash.bkey)) || ((a.bKey || Infinity) - (b.bKey || Infinity))) 
    || (((a.cKey != hash.ckey) - (b.cKey != hash.ckey)) || ((a.cKey || Infinity) - (b.cKey || Infinity)))
  }
}(Object.create(null)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

Comment: @AdityaVijay let me know your feedback on this, thanks!

Comment: its working, what i didn't get is how you made it to bring bKey:2 at first position, will check that and get back to you! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sort()` like this

```js
var data = [{
    aKey:2, 
    bKey:2, 
    cKey:3
}, { 
    bKey:2, 
    cKey:6
}, {
    aKey:1,
    bKey:6, 
    cKey:5
}, {
    cKey:41
}, {
    cKey:7
}, {
    bKey:1, 
    cKey:4
}, {
    bKey:6, 
    cKey:7
}]


data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return ((b.aKey != undefined) - (a.aKey  != undefined) || a.aKey - b.aKey) ||
    ((b.bKey != undefined) - (a.bKey  != undefined) || ((a.bKey != 2) - (b.bKey != 2)) || a.bKey - b.bKey) ||
         ((b.cKey != undefined) - (a.cKey  != undefined) || a.cKey - b.cKey)
})

console.log(data)
```